# Chrome Storage API not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I've tried looking at other projects, but I'm still not sure why my chrome storage project still isn't working. I'm trying to make a chrome extension that allows the user to type something into a text box and click a button that saves the information and puts the information in a span. Also, when I inspect my extension no errors are there, so I'm not exactly sure which part is wrong.

Here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>

<title>Storage</title>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

```
<span id="box"> </span>
<input type ="text" id="card">
<button id="button">Save</button>
```

Here is my js

```
        window.onload=function(){
console.log("yay");
chrome.storage.sync.get("text",function(change){    
    if(change.text){
        document.getElementById("box").innerText=change.text;
    }
});
if(document.getElementById("button")){
    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click",function(){
console.log(documengt.getElementById("card").value);
        var textBox=document.getElementById("card").value;
    console.log(textBox);
        chrome.storage.sync.set({"text":textBox});



document.getElementById("box").innerText=document.getElementById("card").value;
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my manifest:

```
  {
  "manifest_version":2,

  "name": "Storage",
  "description": "This extension allows the user to save information in the box",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
  ]
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you post your manifest?  Also, isn't `val()` jQuery, and not plain js?

Comment: You can check [example](https://gist.github.com/IzumiSy/765cfd6dc02c79de875e0) - it contains basic example of usage storage API as you trying to do.

Comment: Submitting replaces the current page with the server response. In your case it simply reloads the page. Change your `submit` input to a button element.

Comment: Oh ok thanks for everyones help, but for some reason it still does not work

Comment: I've updated my code and also Sergey, the link you put doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is you're not getting the right element in the first place.

You're using document.getElementById("text"); when there's actually no element with id="text". Your input textbox is actually type="text" but id="card".

And also, getting the element just gets the element as an object (it'll show something like [object HTMLInputElement] instad of the text that was actually inside the input box). So you have to use .value to get to the actual text

Just a couple of things to improve, your new storage.js should use

- the right id for the element ("card")
- get the .value of the text input box
- innerText instead of innerHTML (protects against XSS)

As a finished product it looks like:

```
//popup.js
window.onload=function(){
    chrome.storage.sync.get("text",function(change){    
        if(change.text){
            document.getElementById("box").innerText=change.text;
        }
    });
    if(document.getElementById("button")){
        document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click",function(){
            var textBox=document.getElementById("card").value;
            chrome.storage.sync.set({"text":textBox});

        });
    }
}
```

Thanks, MagnetPlant

Edit: changed `storage js` to `popup.js`

Comment: Ok thanks, I agree with the InnerText and .value, but I'm still confused about the storage get because I thought that the id "text" would refer to the one the in the chrome storage. Thanks anyways for your work.

Comment: ```chrome.storage.sync.get("text"...``` and ```document.getElementById("text")``` are two different things.
chrome.storage gets it from the storage for your extension whereas getElementById doesn't get your value from storage, it actually represents the whole <input> element.
If I can be any clearer let me know

Comment: I've changed my js to your final version and kept my html and my manifest the same. Btw, it just displays "//storage html" and i get change it to anythign else when i press the button

Comment: nvm i just change it to anything and it doesnt display anything still

Comment: sorry its not indented but it still doesn't work. Ive also added console.log, but the only thing i get in the console is yay

Comment: I made a basic chrome extension that basically had what you posted and the changes I made, and it works. Maybe you could check your code against here: [github](https://github.com/turquoise-turtle/49503172).
The first time you load the popup nothing shows up, but then you write text and click save, and the next time you open the popup the text you saved shows there.

Comment: Did you check your code against that?
[https://github.com/turquoise-turtle/49503172](https://github.com/turquoise-turtle/49503172)

Comment: Did it work? If it didn't can I see a bit more of your code to see what else could make it not work

Comment: sorry busy these days. Working on anotehr project. It's fine that all the help I need. Thanks! Ill mark as correct if it works in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add this to your **manifest.json**

```
"permissions": [
    "storage",
],
```

As explained in the main table from [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage)

> Permissions:  "storage"

Comment: Yes I did. Here is my manifest{
  "manifest_version":2,

  "name": "Storage",
  "description": "This extension allows the user to save information in the box",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
  ]
}